# Algorithm to delete every files in a directory, except some in a given list

Tags: language-agnostic

Assume we have a directory with structure like this, I marked directories as (+) and files as (-)

```
rootdir
    +a
        +a1
           -f1
           -f2
        +a2
           -f3
    +b
        +b1
           +b2
               -f4
               -f5
           -f6
        +b3
           -f7
           -f8
```

and a given list of files like

```
/a/a1/f1
/b/b1/b2/f5
/b/b3/f7
```

I am struggling to find the way to remove every files inside root, except the one in the given list. So after the program executed, the root directory should look like this:

```
   rootdir
        +a
            +a1
               -f1

        +b
            +b1
               +b2
                   -f5
            +b3
               -f7
```

This example just for easier to understand the problem. In reality, the given list include around 4 thousands of files. And the root directory has the size of ~15GB with a hundreds of thousands files inside.

That would be easy to search inside a folder, and to remove files that matched in a given list. Let just say we solve the revert issue, to keep files that matched in a given list.

Programs written in Perl/Python are prefer.

Comment: In Python, you can use `glob.iglob` to iterate over all files in the directory recursively, and use `os.remove` to remove them unless they're in your blacklist.

Comment: You don't ask for code on SO. Instead you write code and ask for help when you get stuck. Also asking for solutions in python/perl just makes the question too broad, this isn't code golf

Answer (score 2):

First, store your list of files you want to keep inside an associative container like a Python `dict` or a map of some kind.

Second, simply iterate (in Python, `os.walk`) over the entire directory structure, and every time you see a file, check if it is in the associative container of paths to keep.  If not, delete it (in Python, `os.unlink`).

Alternatively:

First, create a temporary directory on the same filesystem.

Second, move (`os.renames`, which generates new subdirectories as needed) all the "keep" files to the temporary directory, with the same structure.

Third, overwrite (`os.removedirs` followed by `os.rename`, or just `shutil.move`) the original directory with the temporary one.

Comment: The alternative might be not helped :). As I know os.walk is pretty slow. I want to improve the code performance

Comment: @AlexPham: Yeah, you *might* achieve faster speed with my alternative approach, but you'll have to test it on your actual system to make sure.  Be sure to create the temporary directory on the same filesystem to avoid slow copying of data.

Answer (score 1):

The `os.walk` path:

```
import os

keep = set(['/a/a1/f1', '/b/b1/b2/f5', '/b/b3/f7'])

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./'):
    for name in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, name).lstrip('.')
        print('check ' + path)
        if path not in keep:
            print('delete ' + path)
        else:
            print('keep ' + path)
```

It doesn't do anything except inform you.

It don't think `os.walk` is too slow, and it gives you the option of keeping by regex patterns or any other criteria.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code for your problem.

```
import os

def list_files(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, name)

files_to_delete = {'/home/vedang/Desktop/a.out', '/home/vedang/Desktop/ABC/temp.txt'} #Keep a set instead of list for faster lookups

for f in list_files('/home/vedang/Desktop'):
    if f in files_to_delete:
        os.unlink(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which accepts a set of files you wish to keep and the root directory from which you wish to begin deleting files.
It's a classic recursive Depth-First-Search that will remove empty directories after deleting all the unwanted files
import os

```
def delete_files(keep_list:set, curr_dir):
    files = os.listdir(curr_dir)

    for f in files:
        path = f"{curr_dir}/{f}"
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            if path not in keep_list:
                os.remove(path)
        elif os.path.islink(path):
                os.unlink(path)
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            delete_files(keep_list, path)

    files = os.listdir(curr_dir)
    if not files:
        os.rmdir(curr_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

here i got a solution in a different aspect,

suppose we are at linux environment,

first,

```
find .
```

to get a long list with all file path/folder explained

second, suppose we got the exclude path list, in order to exclude at your volume ( say thousands ) , we could just append these to the previous list, and

```
 | sort | uniq - c |grep -v "^2"
```

to get the to delete list,

and third

```
 | xargs rm
```

to actually do the deletion